# How to hide the part of one div that extends beyond the boundaries of another div

Tags: jquery, css, html

Imagine two draggable div elements, BIG and SMALL with visible borders. Let's say that SMALL is entirely visible within BIG: you see a rectangle within a rectangle. Now we drag SMALL to the left.As SMALL hits the left border of BIG, I would like SMALL's left border to disappear, followed by more and more of SMALL's content on its left. (This is just the behavior of ordinary application windows on a computer screen.)

My chief question: is this at all possible without extensive Javascript work-- can this be achieved with "mostly" html and css?

Secondary questions: if the answer to the above is "yes", any hints on how to approach this would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try for the BIG div css: overflow:hidden;

Comment: This nails it for default position and relative position. (REMARK: apparently I cannot vote up the answer because I am totally new to stackoverflow and my reputation is too low. Doesn't seem quite fair to the responders.)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the CSS element, overflow: hidden;

For example, see this:
http://jsfiddle.net/PzfLK/

```
<div style="background: red; overflow: hidden; width: 150px; height: 150px;">
    <div style="background: blue; width: 200px; height: 50px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

For more details, view here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Yes,@jordanglue perfect; this applies to the default flow positioning and to relative positioning (which is what jQuery's draggables use and which was my interest). Curiously this does not apply to absolute positioned elements. (REMARK: apparently I cannot vote up the answer because I am totally new to stackoverflow and my reputation is too low. Doesn't seem quite fair to the responders.)